# Nested JSON objects within JSON array

Tags: json

I'm trying to parse the nested JSON object within the JSON array. I'm not sure how to go about accessing all the objects and the Keys and Values within the nested JSON objects in a generic way.

```
     {
        "flights": [
        {
            "ident": "AWI4207",
            "faFlightID": "AWI4207-1505297520-schedule-0000",
            "origin": {
                "code": "KORF",
                "city": "Norfolk, VA",
                "alternate_ident": "",
                "airport_name": "Norfolk Intl"
            },
            "destination": {
                "code": "KPHL",
                "city": "Philadelphia, PA",
                "alternate_ident": "",
                "airport_name": "Philadelphia Intl"
            },
            "filed_ete": 2400,
            "filed_departure_time": {
                "epoch": 1505470320,
                "tz": "EDT",
                "dow": "Friday",
                "time": "06:12AM",
                "date": "15/09/2017",
                "localtime": 1505455920
            },
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here's what i've done so far.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("PathToFile.json"));

JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object.get("flights");
Iterator<Object> eventJSONIterator = jsonArray.iterator();

while (eventJSONIterator.hasNext()) {
  JSONObject jsonEvent = (JSONObject) eventJSONIterator.next();
  System.out.println(jsonEvent.toString());
}
```

I'm able to access the objects but not the sub-objects separately. Is there a way to iterate through the object in the "flights" array and know somehow if i've encountered a JSON Object (e.g. "origin") again and loop inside it? Rather than doing the following

```
JSONObject mainObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);

JSONObject origin = (JSONObject) mainObject.get("origin");
JSONObject destination = (JSONObject) mainObject.get("destination");
JSONObject filed_departure_time = (JSONObject) mainObject.get("filed_departure_time");
```

Also, i want to access the keys as origin_code, origin_city and destination_code, destination_city etc. so as to know which object it belonged to.

Comment: I suppose this is Java. Please tag your question as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("PathToFile.json"));

    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object.get("flights");
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size();i++){
        JSONObject flightJSON = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject origin = flightJSON.getJSONObject("origin");
        String code = origin.get("code");
        String city = origin.get("city");
        String alternate_ident = origin.get("alternate_ident");
        String airport_name = origin.get("airport_name");
        //Similaryly for these
        JSONObject destination = flightJSON.getJSONObject("destination");
        JSONObject filed_departure_time = flightJSON.getJSONObject("filed_departure_time");


    }
```

You need to know the structure  to parse it but if you don't know whether it is array,object or other entities, you can try

```
  Object object = json.get("key");
  if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
   // JSONObject
   jsonArray = (JSONArray)object;
  }else if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
    // JSONArray
    jsonObject = (JSONObject)object;
  }else {
   // String or Integer etc.
 }
```

Comment: jsonArray.length() inside the for loop shows me error for some reason. "The method length() is undefined for the type JSONArray"

Comment: have you imported org.json.JSONArray for JSONArray?

Comment: see the updated answer jsonArray.size() for your case

Comment: Yes. I was using org.json.simple.JSONArray. It worked after making a few adjustments. But i still want to know if there's any way of identifying a JSON object within JSON object without having to look at the JSON array.

Comment: if you don't know the structure then there is no what for rest you can see the updated answer

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please don't forget to accept it @Alohamora153

Comment: Also, i want to access the keys as origin_code, origin_city and destination_code, destination_city etc. so as to know which object it belonged to. Can i change the keys of the object?

Comment: yes you can change the key both on your source and in the parser as you want. update the answer with new keys and i will update the answer correspondingly @Alohamora153